# subset columns based on partial match and group level in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split my dataframe based on a partial match of the column name, using a group level stored in a separate dataframe. The dataframes are here, and the expected output is below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a19-76': [0,1,2],
                        'a23pz': [0,1,2],
                        'a23pze': [0,1,2],
                        'b887': [0,1,2],
                        'b59lp':[0,1,2],
                        'c56-6u': [0,1,2],
                        'c56-6uY': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

ids = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':   ['a19', 'a23', 'b8', 'b59', 'c56'], 
                        'group': ['test', 'sub', 'test', 'pass', 'fail']})
```

desired output

```
test_ids = 'a19-76', 'b887'
sub_ids = 'a23pz', 'a23pze', 'c56-6u' 
pass_ids = 'b59lp'
fail_ids = 'c56-6u', 'c56-6uY'
```

I have written thise onliner, which assigned the group to each column name, but doesnt create two seperate lists as required above

```
gb = ids.groupby([[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith(tuple(i for i in ids.id))], 'group']).agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
gb.groupby('group').agg({'level_0':lambda x: list(x)})
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be not what you are looking for, but anyway.

A pending question is what to do with not matched columns, the answer obviously depends on what you will do after matching.

**Plain python solution**

Simple collections wrangling, but there may be a simpler way.

```
from collections import defaultdict

groups = defaultdict(list)
idsr = ids.to_records(index=False)
for col in df.columns:
    for id, group in idsr:
        if col.startswith(id):
            groups[group].append(col)
            break
    # the following 'else' clause is optional, it creates a group for not matched columns
    else: # for ... else ...
        groups['UNGROUPED'].append(col)
```

Groups =

```
{'sub': ['a23pz', 'c56-6u'], 'test': ['a19-76', 'b887', 'b59lp']}
```

Then after

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(sorted([(k, col) for k,id in groups.items() for col in id]))
```

df =

```
    sub          test           
  a23pz c56-6u a19-76 b59lp b887
0     0      0      0     0    0
1     1      1      1     1    1
2     2      2      2     2    2
```

**pandas solution**

- Columns to dataframe
- product of dataframes (join )
- filtering of the resulting dataframe

There is surely a better way

```
df1 = ids.copy()

df2 = df.columns.to_frame(index=False)
df2.columns = ['col']


# Not tested enhancement:
# with pandas version >= 1.2, the four following lines may be replaced by a single one :
# dfm = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')

df1['join'] = 1
df2['join'] = 1
dfm = df1.merge(df2, on='join').drop('join', axis=1)
df1.drop('join', axis=1, inplace = True)

dfm['match'] = dfm.apply(lambda x: x.col.find(x.id), axis=1).ge(0)
dfm = dfm[dfm.match][['group', 'col']].sort_values(by=['group', 'col'], axis=0)
```

dfm =

```
   group     col
6    sub   a23pz
24   sub  c56-6u
0   test  a19-76
18  test   b59lp
12  test    b887

# Note 1: The index can be removed
# note 2: Unmatched columns are not taken in account
```

then after

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfm)
```

df =

```
group   sub          test           
col   a23pz c56-6u a19-76 b59lp b887
0         0      0      0     0    0
1         1      1      1     1    1
2         2      2      2     2    2
```

Comment: Thank you! Great point about unmatched groups. I would with the pandas code - just compare the ids from the reformatted output with the original input and reinsert a rogue id after. But I really like the pythonic solution. I split the ids to include a multi level column index (Where ids.id is the top level index, and the later characters are the next level) - when i do this the code breaks. I will post updates as I work on it. But thanks so much for this, it really helped me!

Comment: I just realised something - recreating the dataframe to include the labels as in index doesnt work properly - if you change the values in the original df then the order is incorrect `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a19-76': [0,1,2],'a23pz': [3,4,5],'a23pze': [6,7,8],'b887': [9,0,1],'b59lp':[2,3,4],'c56-6u': [5,6,7],'c56-6uY': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})`

Comment: @nac : You need to sort at least for the groups if you want a clean multi-index hierarchy. But in this case (reordering only on groups aka:  `... .sort_values(by=['group'], axis=0)`), I am not sure that the order of ids will be keept.

Comment: oh I see. that makes sense. Well the code you provided does indeed do what I asked originally! thanks again. I wrote the following as a less elegant alternative which might work for others having a similar issue 
`fout=[]
for k, v in groups.items():
   if k in groups:
       d = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(groups[k])]
       d.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[k], d])
       out = pd.concat([d], axis=1)
    fout.append(out)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex generated from the values in `iidf` and `filter`:

Example with "test":

```
s = iddf.set_index('group')['id']

regex_test = '^(%s)' % '|'.join(s.loc['test'])
# the generated regex is: '^(a19|b8|b59)'

df.filter(regex=regex_test)
```

output:

```
   a19-76  b887  b59lp
0       0     0      0
1       1     1      1
2       2     2      2
```

To get a list of columns for each unique group in `iidf`, apply the same process in a dictionary comprehension:

```
{x: list(df.filter(regex='^(%s)' % '|'.join(s.loc[x])).columns)
 for x in s.index.unique()}
```

output:

```
{'test': ['a19-76', 'b887', 'b59lp'],
 'sub': ['a23pz', 'c56-6u']}
```

*NB. this should generalize to any number of groups, however, if really there are **many** groups, it will be preferable to loop on the columns names rather than using `filter` repeatedly*

Comment: hi @mozway, thanks for looking! so I tried applying the code to a larger number of groups - i amended the data in my question to reflect that. If I apply your code now then it doesn't work. I am trying to understand why but I cant figure it out. Would you mind explaining if you have the time? thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward `groupby(...).apply(...)` can achieve this result:

```
def id_match(group, to_match):
    regex = "[{}]".format("|".join(group))
    matches = to_match.str.match(regex)
    return pd.Series(to_match[matches])

matched_groups = ids.groupby("group")["id"].apply(id_match, df.columns)

print(matched_groups)
group
fail   0     c56-6u
       1    c56-6uY
pass   0       b887
       1      b59lp
sub    0     a19-76
       1      a23pz
       2     a23pze
test   0     a19-76
       1      a23pz
       2     a23pze
       3       b887
       4      b59lp
```

You can treat this `Series` as a dictionary-like entity to access each of the groups independently:

```
print(matched_ids["fail"])
0     c56-6u
1    c56-6uY
Name: id, dtype: object

print(matched_ids["pass"])
0     b887
1    b59lp
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Then you can take it a step further to can subset your original `DataFrame` with this new `Series` like so:

```py
print(df[matched_ids["fail"]])
   c56-6u  c56-6uY
0       0      NaN
1       1      NaN
2       2      NaN

print(df[matched_ids["pass"]])
   b887  b59lp
0     0      0
1     1      1
2     2      2
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I am trying to upvote you but dont have the reputation.. I will come back and upvote when I do!